# Create an object from a string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I'm trying to create an object from a string array.

I've this string array :

```
let BaseArray = ['origin/develop', 'origin/master', 'toto/branch', 'tata/hello', 'tata/world'];
```

and I would like to have an object like that :

```
{
  origin : ['develop', 'master'],
  toto : ['branch'],
  tata : ['hello', 'world']
}
```

So for the moment, I did this :

```
let Obj = {};
let RemoteObj = {};
for (let CurrentIndex = 0; CurrentIndex < BaseArray.length; CurrentIndex++) {
    let Splits = BaseArray[CurrentIndex].split('/');
    if (Splits[0] && Splits[1]) {
        Obj[Splits[0]] = Splits[1].trim();
    }

    if (this.isObjectEmpty(RemoteObj)) {
        RemoteObj = Obj;
    } else {
        RemoteObj = this.mergeObjects(RemoteObj, Obj);
    }
    console.log(RemoteObj);
}
```

And my utils functions are :

```
mergeObjects(...objs) {
  let Result = {}, Obj;

  for (let Ind = 0, IndLen = objs.length; Ind < IndLen; Ind++) {
    Obj = objs[Ind];

    for (let Prop in Obj) {
      if (Obj.hasOwnProperty(Prop)) {
        if (!Result.hasOwnProperty(Prop)) {
          Result[Prop] = [];
        }
        Result[Prop].push(Obj[Prop]);
      }
    }
  }

  return Result;
}

isObjectEmpty(Obj) {
  for (let Key in Obj) {
    if (Obj.hasOwnProperty(Key)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a better solution to do it but I can't do it.
So I'm open to any help !

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the object by splitting each string to the key and value, assigning an empty array to the key if it doesn't exist, and pushing the value to the array:

```js
const BaseArray = ['origin/develop', 'origin/master', 'toto/branch', 'tata/hello', 'tata/world'];

const result = BaseArray.reduce((r, str) => {
  const [key, value] = str.split('/');
  
  if(!r[key]) r[key] = [];
  
  r[key].push(value);
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! I tried at the beginning with reduce but I failed due to a bad usage.

Comment: You're welcome. As a rule of thumb - an array to object transformation can usually be done with reduce.

Comment: @OriDrori can we use destructuring assignment to get all the values. For example if a string is like `origin/abc/def` then it will take only `abc`, instead of `abc` &`def`

Comment: If it's a case of nested objects, I wouldn't use destructuring. I would split the path, and then iterate the array of path parts with another loop to build the structure.

Comment: @brk if all of them need to be added in array ['abc','def'] like this than you can use rest parameter

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let BaseArray = ['origin/develop', 'origin/master', 'toto/branch', 'tata/hello', 'tata/world'];

let op = BaseArray.reduce((op, inp) => {
  let [key, value] = inp.split('/')
  op[key] = op[key] || []
  op[key].push(value)
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this approach. On each iteration of reduce you can split your string by `/` and use the first element as a `key` on the new object and then put the second element on the array associated with that `key`:

```js
let BaseArray = ['origin/develop', 'origin/master', 'toto/branch', 'tata/hello', 'tata/world'];

let res = BaseArray.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    let [k, v] = curr.split("/");
    (acc[k] = acc[k] || []).push(v);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reduce` method to build your object.

```js
let baseArray = ['origin/develop', 'origin/master', 'toto/branch', 'tata/hello', 'tata/world'];

let baseobj = baseArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   let items = curr.split('/');
   let key = items[0];
   let value = items[1];
   
   if(acc[key] === undefined) {
      acc[key] = [value] 
   } else {
      acc[key] = [...acc[key], value];
   }
   
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(baseobj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` & `split` the string which will give an array. Then use the element at index 0 of the array to create the `object` key. And push rest of the value to the array

```js
let BaseArray = ['origin/develop', 'origin/kit/sub', 'origin/master', 'toto/branch', 'tata/hello', 'tata/world'];

let newArray = BaseArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let splitCurr = curr.split('/');
  if (!acc[splitCurr[0]]) {
    acc[splitCurr[0]] = []
  }
  for (let i = 1; i < splitCurr.length; i++) {
    acc[splitCurr[0]].push(splitCurr[i])

  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newArray)
```